# Why does List.indexOf use equals method of passed in Object?

Tags: java

In Java, why does the `List<T>.indexOf(Object o)` method use the parameter's equals method rather than the equals method of `<T>`.

This is how it's coded:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
if (o == null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (elementData[i]==null)
        return i;
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

This is how I'd expect it to work:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
if (o == null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (elementData[i]==null)
        return i;
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (elementData[i].equals(o))
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

The second for loop would need to do more null checks when done this second way to avoid any NullPointerException.   Is this the only reason?

Comment: Why does it matter?  `equals` is specified to be symmetric.

Comment: Have you only changed the order of the call? `e.equals(o)` vs `o.equals(e)`? We already know `o` isn't `null`. Also, what @Louis said. ^^^^^

Comment: Isn't the fact that no more null checks need to be performed reason enough?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman it matters because if you override the equals method of <T>, it won't be used in the indexOf method.

Comment: What do you mean by _the equals method of `<T>`_? `T` is a type variable.

Comment: @Keppil I suspect this is the main reason, but was wondering what others had to say.

Comment: @aglassman: _All_ equals methods must be symmetric; it doesn't matter if `o`'s equals method is being used or the list elements' equals methods are being used.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis  Exactly, so whatever type you're using at runtime will have different equals methods.

Comment: (Don't put spaces, use `@name` directly.) I still don't know what you mean (or think you mean).

Comment: @LouisWasserman true, but only if `o != null`, because `o.equals(null)` and `null.equals(o)` are quite different.

Comment: Say you have a class that overrides the equals method, and has a special case for the string object.  It would be useful to pass in the string object, and have the indexOf method use your custom equals method.  I'm guessing this does break the symmetry contract though.

Comment: @Warlord In the implementation shown, `o` cannot be `null` inside the `else` block.

Comment: Are you thinking that the way ArrayList has it, it means that the equals method of `Object` is called?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the ArrayList implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's the point. Because of `null` possibility, you have to do the check and depending on whether you call `equals()` for `o`, or for other elements, you do either a single or many null checks.

Comment: @aglassman Yes but that didn't answer the question I asked. Are you thinking that, for example, if the list has a String in it, calling equals on `o` means String's equals isn't called?

Comment: @Warlord The way I see it, in regards to the change they are proposing, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way ArrayList has it, it avoids null checks. I don't see any other reason. If you call equals on `elementData[i]` you have to check that every element is not null first.

Now, the important part here is that there should not be a difference between the two ways equals could be called.

- First, because the actual equals method called is determined at run time by the actual type of `o`.

This means, for example, if you pass `indexOf` a String, the overridden equals method of String is called, even though the reference type of `o` is Object.

- Second, because [equals is required to be symmetric](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

> It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values **x** and **y**, **x.equals(y)** should return **true** if and only if **y.equals(x)** returns **true**.

If the equals method is properly implemented, which object you call it on will not make a difference.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

The question "why" it's that way, can only be answered by whoever implemented the `List` class. I would say like Louis; it doesn't really matter since the `.equals` is specified to be symmetric. A legit guess would be that it is made sure to use the `.equals` implementation of the object you have provided.

However, if you want its behaviour to change, you could always override it with your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with inheritance. We'll say `Object o` (the parameter) is an instance of a `Cat` object. The `Cat` class, along with every other class, is a descendant of the `Object`, and so `Cat` must have all the same public methods that `Object` does. In `Cat`, we also overrode the `equals(Object other)` method, which is declared by `Object`. `Cat` has its own way it checks if it is equal to another object. If it didn't, you wouldn't be able to tell a `Cat` from a `Dog` from an `Apple` from a `Carburetor` using `equals()`

List, or rather whichever implementation of List you're using (probably ArrayList) identifies `Object o` within its contents using `o`'s `equals()` method. Since (in our example) `o` is a `Cat` object, `o` needs to know if each item in the list is the same thing, and it has to check values that are specific to `Cat`s. When `Cat.equals(Object other)` returns true, `List.indexOf(Object o)` will return the index it was on.

Another way that might be helpful, is to think how `Object.equals(Object other)` would check equality. Object itself only compares the two items' memory addresses. It has nothing else it *can* compare. Even if the Object is really a `Dog`, if `Dog.equals(Object other)` isn't impemented, it cannot compare two Dogs intelligently.

Answer (score -2):

For objects java specifies .equals() method because they cannot be compared directly by '=='.
In case of simple primitive datatypes '==' can be used.
primitive datatypes does not have .equals() method.

Comment: Please clarify how this relates to the question.